# Доступ к расшаренному принтеру из разных подсетей Mikrotik

Tags: mikrotik

Не могу прописать настройки на микротике, чтоб достучатся с подсети 10.0.0.0/8 к компу 192.168.1.100 (nтут расшаренный принтер).
Сеть 10.0.0.0/8 висит на bridge-guest
Сеть 192.168.1.0 висит на bridge-lan

Answer (score 0):

Обычно проблема не в микротике. Если принтер расшарен виндой и в профиле фаервола стоит не "сеть предприятия" - доступ к компу блокируется из других подсетей. Попробуйте переключить профиль или отключить правило в расширенных настройках бржнмауера.